# 「感じさせてくれるところ」の意味と使い方

Tags: meaning

「⚪︎⚪︎を感じさせてくれるところ」 はどういう意味ですか?

Answer (score 5):

[文脈]{ぶんみゃく}によると[思]{おも}いますが、[例]{たと}えば、

> ○○[市]{し}は、[人]{ひと}の[温]{あたた}かさを感じさせてくれるところです。
>   ○○ city is a place which makes you feel the warmth/kindness of people.

のように、「（[場所]{ばしょ}）は、○○を感じさせてくれるところです」と言うときは、「ところ」は「場所(place)」という[意味]{いみ}です。

「感じさせてくれる」は、「感じる」の[使役形]{しえきけい}「感じさせる」(causative form of 感じる)と、[補助動詞]{ほじょどうし}「くれる」からできていて、"to make (me/us/someone) feel ~~" という意味で[使]{つか}います。

上の文は、

> ○○市は、人の温かさを感じることができるところです。
>   ○○ city is a place where you can feel the warmth/kindness of people.

と、言い[換]{か}えることができます。

また、「ところ」には「[部分]{ぶぶん}(part)」という意味もあります。例えば、

> この[作品]{さくひん}の[魅力]{みりょく}は、[未来]{みらい}への[希望]{きぼう}を感じさせてくれるところです。
>   The attraction of this work is that it makes me/you feel hope for the future.
>
> ○○さんの、[安心感]{あんしんかん}を感じさせてくれるところが[好]{す}きです。
>   I like ○○-san because s/he gives me a sense of security/ease.

のように、「○○を感じさせてくれる[点]{てん} (≂ 部分)」"the part (of something/someone) that makes (me/us/someone) feel ~~" という意味で使うことができます。

Answer (score 1):

⚪︎⚪︎を感じさせてくれる is translated as "to make someone feel ⚪︎⚪︎." For example, Yappity yaps of cicadas make me feel summer (セミの鳴き声は、私に夏を感じさせてくれる).

ところ has many meanings. If you use ところ as a place, ⚪︎⚪︎を感じさせてくれる所 is translated as "a place which makes someone feel ⚪︎⚪︎."